# Two conditions in where tag of Liquibase

Tags: sql, database, liquibase

I want to add two conditions in where tag of liquibase and exception is thrown:

```
Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Unknown column 'uid' in 'where clause' [Failed SQL: UPDATE kw.media_file SET created = '1586352959' WHERE id=1 AND uid='admin']
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
```

Here is the changeLog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog 
      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd"
      logicalFilePath="src/main/resources/db/update.xml">

<changeSet author="author" id="20200409-update">
    <update tableName="media_file">
        <column name="last_modified" type="int(11)" value="1586438425"/>
        <where>id=1 AND uid='admin'</where>
    </update>
</changeSet>
```

Equivalent sql statement is here:

```
update person set created = 1586352959 where id = 2 and uid='admin';
```

When I run the SQL statement, the column is updated but no luck with liquibase.

Comment: The error and the XML you shared don't match. The error is about  a table called `kw.media_file`.

Comment: @Mureinik yes, you are I have changed change when I was posting this question, but table name is correct in Exception and changeSet.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the comment - the error and the changeSet you've provided don't match each other.

*The error is that column `uid` is not found in table `media_file`*

Your changeSet is synthetically correct, and you can provide multiple conditions in one `<where>` tag.

Based on the SQL statement you've provided

> update person set created = 1586352959 where id = 2 and uid='admin';

So I can assume the changeSet you're looking for may look something like:

```
<changeSet author="foo" id="bar">
    <update tableName="person">
        <column name="created" type="int(11)" value="1586438425"/>
        <where>id = 2 AND uid = 'admin'</where>
    </update>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake I changed table name in the question, but the name was media_file

Comment: Then I guess the changeSet I've provided in the answer should also be correct.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yes, your answer worked for me. thanks

Comment: Great! If the answer answers your question, you should accept it